# Convert Mercurial (Hg) branches into bookmarks

Tags: mercurial

I have a rather big repository that I started when I was new to Hg.
Recently I learned that the "bookmark" environment is much more fitting for what I am doing compared to the "branches" I introduced.

Now:

> Is there a way to convert branches into bookmarks?

As far as I know mercurial doesn't support this.
Nevertheless I would be very happy if there exists a workaround for that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not directly, but consider using `hg graft` or `hg rebase` (see also `hg transplant`).

Comment: shouldn't this a common task? I was wondering why I couldn't find any instruction for this.

Comment: Can you add some details / examples of the current structure you have vs. the expected structure you would like to achieve?

Comment: I don't know about "common" but if you were to write an extension to do it, you could perhaps make that generally available. See also https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2016-September/049853.html